# REST application folder structure in golang

Tags: rest, go, directory-structure

I'm just getting started with Go and as a first project I decided to make a simple REST API server. Unfortunately, I've hit a problem as I can't seem to find the best way to structure my project.

So far, I'm using the same structure as a Rails project meaning having controllers and models in their own folders, but it doesn't as idiomatic as go code should be.

Does anyone have any advice on how to properly structure a project?

Comment: Folders have a very different semantic meaning in Go than in Ruby. Unfortunately the same way that Rails doesn't can't really be applied to Go.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably do-able, but because of static compilation you're going to have a bit of a mess if you want a lot of Rails' automagic for figuring out routes.

I'd probably just have a `models` package with all the database models, and then something based on [Gorilla's mux](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux) to bind some routes to some actions.

If things are getting complicated you can try a larger framework like [Revel](https://revel.github.io/), which might be more suitable for a larger MVC application.

Comment: Than you. How would you handle model and database ? Would you use an ORM or just call queries to the database directly ?